# How to disable right click for a react bootstrap card?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image: Please see the image first]

If i right click mouse, this option menu pops up. But i want nothing should come. How can i do that?

My Code:

```
 <div>
    <Link to={{
        pathname: "/announcement",
        state: {courseId: this.state.selectedCourseId}
    }}
        className="link">
        <Card className="primaryCardDesign">
            <Card.Header className="primaryCardHeader">
                <Card.Title>
                    Announcement
                </Card.Title>
            </Card.Header>
            <Card.Body className="primaryCardBody">
                A declaration you want to share among the class
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    </Link>
</div>
```

Comment: Any valid reason you want to disable the default browser behaviour?

Comment: If user right click and open it in new tab, some data need to be passed by url. But i am passing it through link here, do not want to pass to by url for security purpose. But if user right click and open it on new tab, app crashes as no data passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onContextMenu` event with an empty handler that prevents the opening of the context menu :

```
 <Card className="primaryCardDesign" onContextMenu={e=>e.preventDefault();}>
```